# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'BMI' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function

I'm mot able to get the BMI value for the combination 'K' & 'I' and 'L'&'C'. But the combination 'K'&'C' and 'L'&'I' works just fine. I tried tinkering with the position of the 'BMI' assignment and elif statement but the function prints a blank BMI value!

Here's the code

```
while True:
weight_unit = input('>kg(K) or lbs(L)? ')
if weight_unit.upper() == 'K':
    weight = int(input('>Enter weight in kg '))
    is_kg = True
    break
elif weight_unit.upper() == 'L':
    weight = int(input('>Enter weight in lbs '))
    is_kg = False
    break
else:
    print('Please enter K or L. ')

while True:
    height_unit = input('>inch(I) or cm(C) ')
    if height_unit.upper() == 'I':
        height = int(input('>Enter height in inch '))
        is_inch = True
        break
    elif height_unit.upper() == 'C':
        height = int(input('>Enter height in cm '))
        is_inch = False
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter I or C.')

def BMI_function(weightt,heightt):
    global BMI
    if is_kg == True:
        if is_inch == False:
            BMI = (weightt/((heightt*0.01)**2))
    elif is_kg == True:
        if is_inch == True:
            heightt = heightt*2.54
            BMI = (weightt/((heightt*0.01)**2))
    elif is_kg == False:
        if is_inch == True:
            BMI = 703*(weightt/(heightt**2))
    elif is_kg == False:
        if is_inch == False:
            height == height*0.393701
            BMI = 703*(weightt/(heightt**2))
    return BMI

BMI_function(weight,height)
```

Comment: If both `is_kg` and `is_inch` are `True`, `BMI` never gets assigned… Follow your code step by step with pen and paper.

Comment: Your first `elif` can never be hit because it has the same condition as the `if` thus BMI won't be set. Same holds for the last `elif`. Thus BMI is not set when `is_kg` and `is_inch` are either both false or both true

Comment: @deceze so how do I fix this error? Why doesn't the elif statement assign BMI?

Comment: @Nuked22 instead of adding so many if-else statements, try something more optimal. Like ```value = (2*int(condition1))+int(condition2)```. That value will be in range [0,3]

Comment: Think through it. `if is_kg == True`, it will enter the first `if`. If `is_inch` is also `True`, that `if is_inch == False` inside the first `if` won't do anything. **Since it has already entered the first `if` block, it will _not_ enter any of the other `elif` blocks,** because that's how `if..elif` works. So you need `if is_inch == False: .. elif is_inch == True: ..` inside the first block to handle both cases.

Comment: (Having said that, this is way too overcomplicated to begin with, but that's another story…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```py
def BMI_function(weightt,heightt):
    global BMI
    if is_kg == True:
        if is_inch == False:
            BMI = (weightt/((heightt*0.01)**2))
    elif is_kg == True:  
        if is_inch == True:
            heightt = heightt*2.54
            BMI = (weightt/((heightt*0.01)**2))
    elif is_kg == False:
        if is_inch == True:
            BMI = 703*(weightt/(heightt**2))
    elif is_kg == False:
        if is_inch == False:
            height == height*0.393701
            BMI = 703*(weightt/(heightt**2))
    return BMI
```

the second and the fourth `elif` branch will never be executed because that's contradictory to the definition of `if .. elif .. else`

A `elif` branch is evaluated if and only if the conditions of all the prior `if` or `elif` (on the same level!) evaluated to false. In your case you have

```
if a == True:
  ...
elif a == True:
  ...
```

Thus if `a` is in fact true, the first condition of `if` evaluates to `true`, thus none of the `elif` conditions is evaluated any more.

A simple solution would be to group together all cases for `is_kg == True` into one branch, where you can add additional `if`s, and all cases for `is_kg == False` into a second branch, again with addtional `if`s inside the branch.

```py
if is_kg == True:
  if is_inch == True:
    BMI = ...
  else:
    BMI = ...
else:
  if is_inc == True:
    BMI = ...
  else:
    BMI = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if is_kg == True:
        if is_inch == False:
            BMI = (weightt/((heightt*0.01)**2))
    elif is_kg == True:
        if is_inch == True:
            heightt = heightt*2.54
            BMI = (weightt/((heightt*0.01)**2))
   ...
```

Here, if `is_kg==True`, the second statement i.e. `elif is_kg==True` wouldn't be executed. Instead of adding so many if-else blocks, you can try something more efficient like:

```
c1 = int(is_kg==True)
c2 = int(is_inch==True)
# using the concept of binary representation i.e. 00,01,10,11
value = (2*c1)+c2  # generates value between 0 and 3
# add remaining actions, based on your value
```